# Running a multi-file program in SLURM

Tags: slurm

I'm going through tutorials on setting up a small SLURM cluster at home and was curious about the following: So far, all the examples/tutorials talk about executing a single line of code, a single python script, or a single executable on the cluster multiple times for different kinds of inputs etc.

In my case, I have a primary python script called main.py that uses modules in several sub-directories, and also has a subdirectory that contains shared C libraries that get used. If I only tell slurm to execute main.py, say, using the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -N 1      
#SBATCH -n 1      
#SBATCH -c 4      
#SBATCH --mem=10  
#SBATCH -t 0:01:00

module load python
python main.py
```

I am going to assume that it is going to choke when main.py is sent to a compute node for processing because the compute node doesn't have any of the python/C dependencies in the subdirectories mentioned before.

Is it necessary for there to be a one file executable that possibly references only pre-installed libraries on all the compute nodes for slurm to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slurm will expect that all dependencies and files are available to the compute node, typically through a network filesystem such as [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), or a parallel filesystem such as [Lustre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_(file_system)) to only name two.

Comment: Ah I see.  So I would put all the dependencies on some folder on the nfs that all the compute nodes have access to and presumably save any outputs from the script to some path on the nfs too.

Comment: Yes that would be the minimal required setup